# Segmentation fault in C python extension

Tags: python, c, docker, alpine-linux, python-extensions

I'm writing a C extension module for python3.7. I have a simple structure as PyObject:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    double attacker;
    double victim;
    double game_hardness;
    int inflation;
} RatingSystem;
```

And initialiser:

```
static int 
RatingSystem_init(RatingSystem *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    double kek;
    static char *kwargs_list[] = {"attacker", "victim", "game_hardness", "inflation"};
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "|$dddi", kwargs_list,
                                      &self->attacker, &self->victim,
                                      &self->game_hardness, &self->inflation)) {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I run it on Mac OS under python 3.7.3, everything works fine, but if I switch to alpine 3.10 python docker image (python:3.7-alpine), On the following initialisation:

```
import rating_system
rs = rating_system.RatingSystem(attacker=1000.0, victim=1000.0, game_hardness=1300.0, inflation=1)
```

I get `Segmentation fault`. Running under gdb showed the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
vgetargskeywords (args=0x7f87284f0050, kwargs=0x7f87284e0a00, format=<optimized out>, format@entry=0x7f8728301000 "|$dddi", kwlist=kwlist@entry=0x7f8728303020 <kwargs_list>, p_va=p_va@entry=0x7ffeeee6e4e0,
    flags=flags@entry=2) at Python/getargs.c:1640
1640    Python/getargs.c: No such file or directory.
```

If I remove `inflation` from init, code works too, i.e. this code:

```
static int 
RatingSystem_init(RatingSystem *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    static char *kwargs_list[] = {"attacker", "victim", "game_hardness"};
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "|$ddd", kwargs_list,
                                      &self->attacker, &self->victim,
                                      &self->game_hardness)) {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Works.

Is there anything wrong with my initialisation? I tried using different types for the last argument, with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords) for `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`, the `keywords` argument expects a NULL-terminated array of keyword parameter names.

Add an additional `NULL` element to your `kwargs_list`:

`static char *kwargs_list[] = {"attacker", "victim", "game_hardness", NULL};`